# Call EventMachine defer within callback?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I'm using `EventMachine.defer` to handle some long-running processes (an indefinite wait for a response from an outside application). I want to do this in a loop: each time the application responds, I process the response and then immediately want to start waiting for the next response.

My code currently looks like this:

```ruby
def watch_for_songs_change
  EM.defer(
    ->( ){ `mpc idle playlist` }, # wait for the song list to change
    ->(_){ update_songs; watch_for_songs_change }
  )
end
```

I realized that this is calling `defer` from within a callback from `defer`. Is this valid? Am I spawning one thread from inside another, and will eventually run out of threads? Or does EventMachine invoke the callback after it has returned the thread to the pool?

Comment: Does `mpc idle playlist` block until the playlist has changed? if not, then using `EM.defer` doesn't really gain you much here.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to chain calls like this before in EM, and found that using periodic timers is a usually a better design.

```rb
@timer = EventMachine.add_periodic_timer( 1 ) { `mpc idle playlist` and update_songs }
```